# Wi-Fi very slow at 15.04 with card Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak] when download something

Tags: networking, wireless, 15.04, intel-wireless

I have very strange behaviour with Wi-Fi at my Ubuntu 15.04 at laptop Lenovo Ideapad Y570. I have perfect internet connection if connect cable to my Ethernet directly. But with Wi-Fi if I download something (even web page) internet speed become very slow. Not only internet, even local resources like router configuration page. The normal ping near 30ms. If I opening web-page it is 500-900ms. If I download something big it can be 16000-20000ms and even more. Looks like that it connected to download time: when you download something ping increasing with each next packet - longer downloading process = bigger ping in result. My girlfriend doesn't see this problem at her Windows 7 laptop. I also don't see this problem at my Ubuntu Phone.

Disconnecting from Wi-Fi and connecting again solves problem for few seconds. What can be wrong?

My lshw:

```
   *-network
        description: Wireless interface
        product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
        vendor: Intel Corporation
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
        logical name: wlan0
        version: 00
        serial: 74:e5:0b:ee:f5:94
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
        configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.19.0-28-generic firmware=39.31.5.1 build 35138 ip=192.168.1.108 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
        resources: irq:33 memory:f1b00000-f1b01fff
```

Router is TP-Link TL-WR740N/ND v4  with firmware: OpenWrt Barrier Breaker 14.07 / LuCI Trunk (0.12+svn-r10530)

Ubuntu and kernel version:

```
robotex@robotex-laptop:~$ uname -a
Linux robotex-laptop 3.19.0-28-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 31 15:52:51 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
robotex@robotex-laptop:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

Comment: Did you enable the firewall(UFW)?

Comment: If it not enabled by default - No.

Comment: Is the wifi router using WPA2 only with no TKIP or WEP?

Comment: Encryption: WPA2 PSK (CCMP)

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled the aggressive TX with

```
echo "option iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlopt.conf
```

followed by rebooting

Comment: Did it. Didn't help.